# Can I proxy pass the root to one address and the rest to the other address in nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have this proxy pass in my nginx configuration.

```
location /content {
proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
proxy_pass $address1;
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
   add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
   add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
   return 204;
}
if ($request_method = 'POST') {
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
}
if ($request_method = 'GET') {
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
}
```

}

I would like to proxy_pass `/content` to `$address1` but I would like to proxy_pass any other `/content/something_else` to `$address2` is this possible in nginx?

For example if I hit `http://www.example.com/content?some_other_param=value` it would be forwarded to `http://www.content.com` but if I hit `http://www.example.com/content/article?some_param=value` it would hit `http://www.different_content.com`

Comment: if my answer answers the question, can you please +1?  if not, let me know what's missing.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to proxy_pass `/content` to `$address1` but I would like to proxy_pass any other `/content/something_else` to `$address2` is this possible in nginx?

Yes.  You can use a `location = /content` w/ `$address1`, and `location /content` w/ `$address2`; this would be the preferred configuration especially if the two addresses don't share all that much.